# Draw circle under finger android canvas

Tags: android, canvas, bitmap, position, draw

Good day!
I faced such a problem that I need to draw a circle under the touch of my finger.

I tried to use the following code:

```
private fun pressFinger() {
    mFirst.setOnTouchListener(View.OnTouchListener { v, event ->
        val x = event.x
        val y = event.y
        
        when (event.action) {
            MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN -> {
                drawCircle(x, y)
            }
        }

        return@OnTouchListener true
    })
}
fun drawCircle(x: Float, y: Float) {
    val width: Int = x.toInt()
    val height: Int = y.toInt()

    val bitmap = (mFirst.getDrawable() as BitmapDrawable).bitmap
    val workingBitmap: Bitmap = Bitmap.createBitmap(bitmap)
    val mutableBitmap = workingBitmap.copy(Bitmap.Config.ARGB_8888, true)

    val canvasBitmap = Canvas(mutableBitmap)

    val paint = Paint(Paint.ANTI_ALIAS_FLAG)
    paint.style = Paint.Style.FILL
    paint.xfermode = PorterDuffXfermode(PorterDuff.Mode.CLEAR)

    canvasBitmap.drawCircle(width.toFloat(), height.toFloat(), 180F, paint)
    mFirst.setImageBitmap(mutableBitmap)
    drawUtils.draw()
}
```

The problem is that the circle is not drawn under the finger, but on the side.

I also want to note that the image placed inside the ImageView has a larger size and I use scaleType = "cropCenter".
It turns out that I need to get the position of the finger exactly on the image placed in the ImageView, and not just on the screen.

If someone knows the correct answer to the question, I would be grateful.

Answer (score 0):

This is really bad code.  Why are you editing the background image in the view?  The easier thing would be to save the coordinates in the onTouch function, then invalidate the view.  Then in the view's onDraw, you draw a circle at that location.  This way you avoid all the scaling issues, and you don't have to make 2 COPIES!!! of the bitmap which is horribly inefficient.

Answer (score -1):

canvasBitmap.drawCircle(width.toFloat() - 180F / 2, height.toFloat() - 180F / 2, 180F, paint)

Have a try.

Comment: Shouldn't be needed.  According to the docs on draw circle, the coordinates are the center of the circle.  This would be correct if it was the lower right hand corner.